# OutputDebugString doesn't print information in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7-x64

I've been trying to get `OutputDebugString` to work with no avail. My code follows:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    OutputDebugStringA("asd");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the application without debugging, DebugView shows `asd` but when I debug my application (F5), it doesn't print my string in Output or Intermediate window.

I've tried OutputDebugString with `asd` but nothing changed. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should terminate the string with "\n", but this should be only a cosmetic thing. I have tried your code right now and I can see the asd string in the Output window of VS 2010 without any issues.

Note: in the context menu of the Output pane (accessible using right mouse click) you can select which information should be displayed in the pane. Make sure you have enabled "Program output". Also make sure you are watching the correct window (Output or Immediate) depending on your setting "Redirect all Output window text to the Immediate window" in Tools/Options/Debugging/General.

Comment: This helps DebugView print asd without appending to the next debug string, but "asd\n" doesn't help the main issue.

Comment: Thanks for your interest but your edited text didn't help either. It was disabled at first but enabling it didn't change output, the problem persists.

Comment: I'm sorry, I read somewhere that the output may go to Intermediate window instead so I changed the settings that forward output messages to Intermediate window. So, you were right in your note.

Answer (score 4):

We had a similar issue with x64 mixed mode debugging, so if you are using 64 bit check the Debugging property page for the main startup project. The Debugger Type should be set to 'Mixed' rather than 'Auto' to see native as well as managed debug output.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234560/outputdebugstring-does-not-work-on-windows-7x64) for more info.